# Issue with converting parameterized SQL to HQL

Tags: grails, groovy, hql

We are using grails-groovy with Hibernate, I have a SQL query like this in my grails controller

```
    String markerCalcQuery =
    "select sum(trans_cnt) as t_count, location  from map2_data where "+
    "fdate between (:datefrom) and (:dateto) "+
    "and res_id=:res_id "+
    "group by location ;"

   res_row=gurculsql.rows(markerCalcQuery,[res_id:res_id,datefrom:format_dateprevious,dateto:format_datenow]);
```

How do I change this query to HQL, I don't have a domain class `map2_data`, but want to know if I need to create it for converting this query to HQL, or can I convert it without doing that (should use gorm based implementation)?

I have many queries right now written for MySQL and I need to convert them to HQL.

I have now created the domain class `map2_data`. So how would the above query change (how to decide the functions... out of findallby, createcriteria, etc)

Regards,

Priyank

Comment: if map2_data table is not mapped to a domain, how are you performing actions(both read and write) on fields like t_count and location in your program?

Comment: these are summary tables I have insert scripts which populate data in these tables from other table like tansaction, user, resource, etc..

Comment: If you plan to convert all your sql queries to hql queries, you'll have to create an entity to map to your map2_data table. Otherwise, there's no other way (via hql) to insert/update/read records from this table.

Comment: How would I write this query with map2_data as a domain class..

Comment: If map2_data is a domain class, the hql would be the same as the sql query you have mentioned above. All the clauses that you have used in your sql query are   are valid hql clauses as well. Just change the table name and columns to your entity name and attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL works on Hibernate entities. If you don't have an entity to map your table, you can't use HQL on this table. That's the principle of an ORM: use objects to represent tables.

Comment: My main goal is to make the queries generalised, so that they work with MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL and some other vendors like Hadoop etc.. SO I need to make the query generalised. How do I go about doing that..?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean here. If you chose Hibernate as a way to access the database in a database-agnostic way, do the same for this table: map it as an entity, and translate the SQL query to HQL. If you don't want to use Hibernate to access the table, then use a DAOFactory that will return a MySQLDAO containing the MySQL query, a HadoopDAO containing the Hadoop query, etc. depending on the configuration of the application.